# Defining equicontinuity in terms of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity, equicontinuity

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of uniformly continuous functions on $X$. Is it true that if I can show that for **any** convergent sequence $x_n$, $x_n \rightarrow x$, there exists an N such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $k > N$, $|f_n(x_k)-f_n(x)| < \epsilon$, then $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous?

The reason I think this is true is that, it seems like the choice of $N$ is analogous (or at least very intimately tied to) to the choice of $\delta$ at the limit point. But, most of the proofs that show sequence preservation and epsilon-delta continuity equivalence, don't find the actual delta, so I'm not sure how to prove my idea.

Comment: This is rue if X is compact. I believe it is false in general.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to prove it for compact X?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X = [0,1]$ with the standard metric and $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x > 0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

Then all $f_n$ are continuous and because $[0,1]$ is compact in $\Bbb R$ also uniformly continuous but $\{f_n\}$ is not equicontinuous in $0$

Now take $x_n = \frac{1}{n\pi}$ then it holds $f_n(x_k) = 0$ for all $n,k \in \Bbb N$ and so $$|f_n(x_k)-f_n(x)| = 0 < \varepsilon$$ so your condition holds but still: $\{f_n\}$ is not equicontinuous in $0$

The result may differ if you claim that your condition hold for all convergent sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ with $x_n \to x$

Comment: I think the condition of jackssons5 is supposed to hold for every convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$, though the wording is imprecise. If this is the right interpretation then his claim is  true whenever X is a compact, in particular for $X=[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I did intend for it to hold for all convergent sequences.

Comment: If K is compact you can prove this by contradiction. If $\{f_n\}$ is not equicontinuous then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and sequences $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ such that $|x_n -y_n| <1/n$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq 2\epsilon$. There is a subsequence  $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ converging to some point x. Since $|x_n -y_n| <1/n$ we see that $\{y_{n_k}\}$ also converges to x.  Now apply the hypothesis to $\{x_{n_k}\}$ and $\{y_{n_k}\}$ and use triangle inequality to get $|f(x_{n_k})-f(y_{n_k})|< 2\epsilon$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Assume that $\{f_n\}$ is not equicontinuous. Then there are $x\in X$, $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there are $y\in X$ and $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ but $|f_m(x)-f_m(y)|\ge \varepsilon$. Plug in $\delta=1/n$ and call the corresponding $y=x_n$ to arrive at a contradiction.